# Debug .htaccess syntax error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, syntax, server

I have the following code:

```
# Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^salom.dev[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.salom.dev/$1 [r=301,nc]

# 301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 /admin(.*) /vendor/aheinze/cockpit/$1

# Change default directory page
DirectoryIndex /site

# Prevent viewing of .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

# Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes
```

I keep getting 500 errors but I can't find the problem any ideas?

Here is the conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName salom.dev

        DocumentRoot /home/otis/Developer/salom
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/otis/Developer/salom/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also is there a way to debug these errors using the dev tools or potentially the logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DirectoryIndex` is a file not a directory and you have a missing space before `[nc].

Try this .htaccess:

```
# Change default directory page
# DirectoryIndex /site

# Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^salom\.dev$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# 301 Redirect Entire Directory
RewriteRule ^admin(.*) /vendor/aheinze/cockpit/$1 [L,NC,R=301]

# Prevent viewing of .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Is still happening, it takes me to `salom.dev/site/` which is want but still throws 500 error.

Comment: Check your Apache error.log for exact error and try clearing browser cache.

Comment: Have enabled mod_rewrite but now it is saying `/site/` does not exist on the server and it does.

Comment: Does `site` directory exist under `/home/otis/Developer/salom`? Also what rule is routing to `site/` when I commented out `DirectoryIndex` line?

Comment: It does sorry was to do with www prefix